# Phantom space between parent element and svg

Tags: css, svg

I have a project I'm working on and bumped into a strange misalignment of the parent element and the SVG contained inside.

[image]

The light blue spot is where chrome says the `<whole-rest>` element is located and the black rectangle below it is the `<svg>` that is inside the `<whole-rest>`

HTML

```
<measure>
  <svg style="width: 100px;">
    <line stroke="black" stroke-width="2" x1="0" y1="10" y2="10" x2="100"></line>
    <line stroke="black" stroke-width="2" x1="0" y1="20" y2="20" x2="100"></line>
    <line stroke="black" stroke-width="2" x1="0" y1="30" y2="30" x2="100"></line>
    <line stroke="black" stroke-width="2" x1="0" y1="40" y2="40" x2="100"></line>
    <line stroke="black" stroke-width="2" x1="0" y1="50" y2="50" x2="100"></line>
  </svg>
  <whole-rest>
    <svg>
      <rect height="5" width="10" fill="black"></rect>
    </svg>
  </whole-rest>
  <single-barline>
    <svg>
      <line stroke="black" stroke-width="1" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="40"></line>
    </svg>
  </single-barline>
</measure>
```

CSS

```
measure {
  height: 60px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

measure > svg {
  height: 60px;
}

whole-rest {
  height: 5px;
  width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
}

whole-rest > svg {
  height: 5px;
  width: 10px;
}
```

Also if it matters I am using the Eric Meyers 2.0 CSS reset, browser is Chrome.

I have tried setting the `whole-rest` to `display:block` and also messed with `overflow` since sometimes those can help with floating / maligned items.

No elements have any margin or padding (with the exception of the `margin-left: -5px` on the `whole-rest` to center the element with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: absolute;` to `.whole-rest > svg { ... }`

Comment: Bingo! Perfect. Thank you very much. Will accept once timer has finished.